# Dynamic form in Asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to work on a dynamic form which will be generated based on database table.

For example i have product Table with `ID & Name` columns

and i have following records in the table.

**ID   Name**

```
1  Name One
2  Name Two
3  Name Four
4  Name Five
```

Now i need to generate a dynamic form in asp.net webform using data from this table.

Form will be similar to what is shown here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gLNByB

I have not sure how to make it work with following tasks

1. I have to generate form dynamically
2. I have to pass these values & amount of Checked Checkbox & store them in Different table. (Values to be store will be `ID & Amount`

Any pointer in this regard would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

**I have to generate form dynamically**

You have to create your controls dynamicly in your OnInit EventHandler. You can loop over your data and create the needed Controls.

**I have to pass these values & amount of Checked Checkbox & store them in Different table. (Values to be store will be ID & Amount**

May you have a SubmitButton, on the btn_Click EventHandler, you can access the control values and do with them what ever you want.